# how can i use php to get if any number is have a decimal point and also to count the decimal point using conditional statement

Tags: php

```
if (is_float($num)) {
        $n = explode (".", $num);
        var_dump($n);
        if (count($n) == 2){
        $dp = $n[1];
       }
   else {
        $dp = count($n);
       }
    }
else{
    $dp = "The number is not  a decimal number";
  }
```

This is my code but still not working

i have us if statement and still not working

Comment: Please provide more context than "not working". Do you get an error? What does `$num` contain; have you debugged that value?

Comment: `$dp = strlen($n[1]);` might be the answer but with no context can't really say.

Answer (score 0):

if are you looking alternative way to count decimal point, check this out

```
$num = 20.1234;

if (is_float($num)) {

  $dp = strlen(substr(strrchr($num, "."), 1));
  echo $dp;

    } else
     {

    $dp = "The number is not  a decimal number";
    echo $dp;
  }
```

Result
4

Explanation

1. convert the `$num` to a string and then use `strrchr` to find the
   portion of the string after the decimal point.
2. `substr` to extract the decimal portion after the dot `.123`
3. `strlen` to count the decimal points.

Comment: What issue are you solving with this?